# On max-min representation for the principal eigenvalue of nonsymmetric elliptic operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

> [image]

---

I've tried to proceed by way of the hint, but I'm at a loss of how that would be useful. It seems that considering the adjoint of $L$ would only be useful if the expression involved the inner product on $L^2$ or the bilinear form associated with $L$ (-then perhaps I would try using the Rayleigh quotient to get out something useful). But given that the expression involves only $Lu(x)$ and $u(x)$, I'm not sure how I would relate that to the adjoint. A pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.